# Использование несовершенного вида в будущем времени

Tags: выбор-слов, глаголы, правила

Вроде тупой вопрос, но я где-то прочитал это предложение:

> Жена: Ладно, смотри сам. Только я завтра заказываю билеты на самолёт туда-обратно

Очевидно, она закажет билеты только один раз. Почему здесь использован несовершенный вид?

Comment: А вдруг не закажет ни разу. Может она не любит давать утвердительные прогнозы на будущее. Может муж палки в колёса поставит. Может ответ на заказ придет послезавтра. В конце концов какая разница будет она заказывать или закажет если из одного прямо следует другое.

Comment: @user190920 понятно, можно сказать "только завтра я буду заказывать"? в данном случае?

Comment: "Буду заказывать" это будущее время, так конечно можно сказать. Но можно сказать и настоящим временем: "завтра заказываю", здесь явно указана привязка к завтрашнему дню. Можно даже сказать: "Вчера заказываю билеты и тут подходит он"

Comment: @user190920 C последним **не** соглашусь - нельзя так о вчерашнем: даже если говорят глядя в записи какого-нибудь ежедневника, употребимо только прошедшее время (посмотрим-ка, что я "делал" вчера, -  в значении "должен был делать"). Зато в контексте _планируемого_ будущего (по тому же ежедневнику и т. п., да и в любой разговорной ситуации) грамматическое настоящее вполне употребимо: (посмотрим-ка, что я там завтра делаю... ага, билеты заказываю.).

Comment: И о вчерашнем можно рассказать глаголом несовершенного вида в настоящем вемени . Почему нет? « Стою я вчера в кассе, билеты заказываю — и вижу ...»

Comment: Это другое, перенос _повествования_ о прошлом в настоящее время, - о _реально_ случившихся событиях. В контексте же будущего речь о том, чего _не было_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Только я завтра заказываю/ буду заказывать/ закажу билеты на самолёт туда-обратно.

Все три варианта правильные, и все можно употреблять для разового действия.
Разница в степени вероятности заказа, как тут уже указывали в комментариях, семантика (модальность) глагола влияет на выбор формы.
В первом случае настоящее время употребляется для обозначения будущего запланированного контролируемого действия ( в английском то же самое). Наибольшая вероятность выражена глаголом совершенного вида.
Источник очень подробный, но предназначен для специалистов.

[http://rusgram.ru/Будущее_время](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%91%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F)

Comment: Хороший источник, спасибо!